# How can I replace [Calendly] with my company name in the order invoice summary for Shopify and Stripe payments integration?

Tags: stripe-payments, shopify, invoice

How to remove the [Calendly] from the order invoice.

I have integrated Calendly into my Shopify website for event bookings, and Stripe is set up as the payment gateway. When an event is booked, the booking person receives an order invoice. The issue I'm facing is that the invoice summary appears as follows:

[Calendly] 30 Minute Meeting with Deepu Gopi $0.50

I would like to replace "[Calendly]" with the name of my company. I have searched for a solution but haven't found a way to make this change. Could someone please assist me in updating the invoice summary with the company name?

I have tried exploring the settings in Calendly and reviewing the email templates related to the order invoice. However, I was unable to find a specific option to modify the invoice summary or remove the '[Calendly]' tag. I was expecting to locate a setting that would allow me to customize the invoice summary with my company name instead. Unfortunately, my attempts thus far have been unsuccessful in achieving the desired outcome.

Comment: Is the Calendly and Stripe integration on the website done custom or using any 3rd party app?

Comment: The Calendly and Stripe integration on the website is done using the built-in option provided by Calendly. It allows users to integrate Stripe for payment processing seamlessly. There is no need for any custom development or third-party apps for this integration.